# SQL SErver Trigger not evaluating as Insert or Update properly

Tags: triggers, insert

I want to have one trigger to handle updates and inserts.  Most of the sql actions in the trigger are for both.  The only exception is the fields I'm using to record date and username for an insert and an update.  This is what I have, but the updates of the fields used to track update and insert are not firing right.  If I insert a new record, I get CreatedBy, CreatedOn, LastEditedBy, LastEditedOn populated, with LastEditedOn as 1 second after CreatedOn (which I dont want to happen).  When I update the record, only the LastEditedBy & LastEditedOn changes (which is correct).  I'm including my full trigger for reference:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
-- =================================================================================
-- Author:  Paul J. Scipione
-- Create date: 2/15/2012
-- Update date: 6/5/2012
-- Description: To concatenate several fields into a set formatted UnitDescription,
--              to total Span & Loop footages, to set appropriate AcctCode, & track
--              user inserts
-- =================================================================================
IF OBJECT_ID('ProcessCable', 'TR') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TRIGGER ProcessCable
GO
CREATE TRIGGER ProcessCable
ON Cable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1 RETURN

IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) > 1 )
  RETURN
ELSE
  BEGIN
  -- record user and date of insert or update
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    UPDATE Cable SET LastEditedOn = getdate(), LastEditedBy = REPLACE(user_name(), 'GRTINET\', '')
  ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    UPDATE Cable SET CreatedOn = getdate(), CreatedBy = REPLACE(user_name(), 'GRTINET\', '')

  -- reset Suffix if applicable
  UPDATE Cable SET Suffix = NULL WHERE Suffix = 'n/a'

  -- create UnitDescription value
  UPDATE Cable SET UnitDescription =
    isnull (Type, '') +
    isnull (CONVERT (NVARCHAR (10), Size), '') +
    '-' +
    isnull (CONVERT (NVARCHAR (10), Gauge), '') +
    CASE
      WHEN ExtraTrench IS NOT NULL AND ExtraTrench > 0 THEN
        CASE
          WHEN Suffix IS NULL THEN 'TE' + '(' + CONVERT (NVARCHAR (10), ExtraTrench) + ')'
          ELSE 'TE' + '(' + CONVERT (NVARCHAR (10), ExtraTrench) + ')' + Suffix
        END
      ELSE isnull (Suffix, '')
    END

  -- convert any accidental negative numbers entered
  UPDATE Cable SET Length = ABS(Length)

  -- sum Length with LoopFootage into TotalFootage
  UPDATE Cable SET TotalFootage = isnull(Length, 0) + isnull(LoopFootage, 0)

  -- set proper AcctCode based on Type
  UPDATE Cable SET AcctCode =
    CASE
      WHEN Type IN ('SEA', 'CW', 'CJ') THEN '32.2421.2'
      WHEN Type IN ('BFC', 'BJ', 'SEB') THEN '32.2423.2'
      WHEN Type IN ('TIP','UF') THEN '32.2422.2'
      WHEN Type = 'unknown' OR Type IS NULL THEN 'unknown'
    END
  WHERE AcctCode IS NULL OR AcctCode = ' '

END

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things jump out at me when I look at your trigger:

- You are doing several additional updates rather than a single update (performance-wise, a single update would be better).
- Your update statements are unconstrained (there is no JOIN to the inserted/deleted tables to limit the number of records that you perform these additional updates on).
- Most of this logic feels like it should be in the application layer rather than in the database; Or, perhaps in some cases implemented differently.

Some quick examples:

- Suffix of "n/a" should be removed before inserted.
- Cable length absolute value should be done before inserted (with a CHECK CONSTRAINT to verify that bad data cannot be inserted).
- TotalFootage should be a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) so it is always correct.
- The Type/AcctCode relationship seems like it should be a column value in a foreign key reference.

But ultimately, I think the reason you are seeing the unexpected dates is because of the unconstrained updates.  Without addressing any of the other concerns I brought up above, the statement that sets the audit fields should be more like this:

```
UPDATE Cable SET LastEditedOn = getdate(), LastEditedBy = REPLACE(user_name(), 'GRTINET\', '')
FROM Cable
    JOIN deleted on Cable.PrimaryKeyColumn = deleted.PrimaryKeyColumn

UPDATE Cable SET CreatedOn = getdate(), CreatedBy = REPLACE(user_name(), 'GRTINET\', '')
FROM Cable
    JOIN inserted on Cable.PrimaryKeyColumn = inserted.PrimaryKeyColumn
    LEFT JOIN deleted on Cable.PrimaryKeyColumn = deleted.PrimaryKeyColumn
WHERE deleted.PrimaryKeyColumn IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips on the other parts of my code.  I tried your join syntax to constrain the audit field updates and got the same results.  The one constant in the variations of code I am testing is that the CreatedOn only gets set once, on initial insert.